# Django many to many model get none

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, orm

I have been dealing with a project for a few days and today I encountered an error. I wanted to write it here as I have no idea how to solve it.

My first model:

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    video_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/' , blank=True, null=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField('categories.Category', blank=True)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/video/" + self.video_slug
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Videos"
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        get_latest_by = 'created_at'
```

secondary model:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='category', blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/category/" + self.category_slug
    
    class Meta: 
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"
        ordering = ['name']
```

and view.py

```py
...

class VideoListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer
```

When i send get request i got this

```json
[
    {
         ...
        "category": "categories.Category.None",
        ...
    }
]
```

What should i do? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Im assuming your mistake is you are using an empty Serializer and not including the `queryset` instance. So something like this will fix your issue:

```
queryset = Video.objects.all()
serializer_class = VideoSerializer(queryset, many=True)
```

Comment: I added this category = ManyRelatedField(child_relation=CharField(max_length=100)) to my serializer and work. Thank you.